# rewrite native javascript in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a native JavaScript function and I'd like to rewrite it in jQuery. Can you help me? Way beyond my understanding...

EDIT: Quickly addressing the "please refactor my code for me" comments- I'm not asking you to rewrite the work, I'd simply like some guidance on how to rewrite this. As you all have experienced at some point, documentation, tutorials, and books that are helpful can be difficult to find. Any advice is welcome, but..

```
if(you dont have anything nice to say){
    dont
}



 var RESIZER = function(){ 

    this.prevWidth = resizee.offsetWidth;
    this.prevHeight = resizee.offsetHeight;

    this.resizee = resizeeContainer.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    this.resizeeContainer = resizee.parentNode;
    this.resizeeStyle = this.resizee.style;

    var ratio = this.resizee.offsetHeight/this.resizee.offsetWidth;

    var that = this;

    this.Init = function(){
        if( that.resizeeContainer.className.lastIndexOf("resizerd")>=0 )
        {
            var resizeeContOffsetWidth = that.resizeeContainer.offsetWidth;
            var resizeeOffsetWidth = that.resizee.offsetWidth;
            var resizeeContOffsetHeight = that.resizeeContainer.offsetHeight;
            var resizeeOffsetHeight = that.resizee.offsetHeight;

            if(that.prevWidth!= resizeeContOffsetWidth)
            {
                that.prevWidth = resizeeContOffsetWidth;
                var desired = resizeeContainer.offsetHeight/resizeeContainer.offsetWidth;
                if(desired>ratio){
                    that.resizeeStyle.width=resizeeContOffsetWidth*desired+resizeeContOffsetWidth*desired+"px";
                    that.resizeeStyle.left = -1*(resizeeOffsetWidth-resizeeContOffsetWidth)/2+'px';
                }
                else{ 
                 that.resizeeStyle.cssText="width:100%;height:auto;position:fixed;";
                }
            }

            if(that.prevHeight!=resizeeContOffsetHeight)
            { 
                that.prevHeight = resizeeContOffsetHeight;
                var desired = resizeeContOffsetHeight/resizeeContOffsetWidth;  
                if(desired>ratio){  console.log(ratio);
                    //that.resizeeStyle.top = '0px';
                    that.resizeeStyle.left = -1*(resizeeOffsetWidth-resizeeContOffsetWidth)/2+'px';
                    that.resizeeStyle.width = resizeeContOffsetHeight*desired+resizeeContOffsetHeight/desired+'px';
                }
                else
                {
                    that.resizeeStyle.top = -1*(resizeeOffsetHeight-resizeeContOffsetHeight)/2+'px';

                }
            }

        }
    };
};

var myResizerObject = new RESIZER();
window.onresize = myResizerObject.Init;
```

Comment: Why does it need to be in jQuery?

Comment: Probably not the right forum. I'd recommend you take a stab at doing this yourself and if you get stuck on any specific detail come back with a question pertaining to that. Also, why do you want to re-write it using JQuery? What benefit are you perceiving?

Comment: @Jared Farrish - doesn't NEED to be.. one of you JavaScript warriors helped work it out and I wanted to combine it with some jQuery I wrote to center the resized element on to the page and launch it on load. I made an attempt, but with no luck. See my previous post. I've made mods to the native function since. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401403/help-combining-native-javascript-and-jquery-function-into-one-library

Comment: If you have a project that is entirely in jQuery and there are sections in pure javascript, then you may want to refactor that to match the style of the rest of the work.  Not uncommon

Comment: @Khepri This one's just beyond me. I'm able to fumble around in native script, but not as nimbly as I need to be to accomplish this. As I explained to Jared, working with it in jQuery would allow me to combine it with another function I have

Comment: @technopeasant - The problem with this on SO is that "please refactor this code for me" is not really a question. For short snippets, sure, folks get away with it, but not necessarily in the case of what appears to be an entire plugin. :)

Comment: @Jared Farrish - I totally hear you. Can you suggest any resources that would help me get started? I might be able to rework the jQuery into native script and combine them from there. Although I've read some saying that browsers interpret native differently..??

Comment: @technopeasant - If you haven't gone through the jQuery beginner plugin tutorial, I would: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring Try developing a simple plugin first, like an input field validation plugin or something. I'm not sure what you mean by the native script and browsers interpreting differently; some JS is browser-dependent. jQuery-native functions should be browser-agnostic.

Comment: @Jared Farrish - thanks for the direction and advice. I was planning on making something simple to teach myself.. And an opportunity came up to try and help some friends out with a.. significantly more complicated project: resizing a video (or image) to always be edge to edge (like Supersized). You've helped me out on several questions over the past couple months and I've noticed that you're very knowledgable and thorough. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Jared Farrish - also, please repost your last comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developing jQuery plugins, while not real difficult, is not trivial either. The only way to do it is to start with a tutorial and learn the ins and outs. Then you can take a piece of code and turn that code into a functioning plugin. But you have to learn some things first.

If you haven't gone through the jQuery beginner plugin tutorial, I would: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring Try developing a simple plugin first, like an input field validation plugin or something.

I'm not sure what you mean by the native script and browsers interpreting differently; some JS is browser-dependent. jQuery-native functions should be browser-agnostic.

Comment: I've read in a few places that browsers can interpret native JavaScript differently, and that one of jQuery's advantages is that it is, as you say, browser-agnostic. I probably misunderstood.

Comment: @technopeasant - There are certainly things that work in some browsers but not in others (`try catch` used to be lazily supported, for instance). That's getting to be less of an issue as browsers become more standard. jQuery certainly aims to minimize those differences.

Comment: @Jarred Farrish - ah, I see. Thanks again for your wisdom.