# Help converting JavaScript click function to onLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, window, onload

I'm trying to convert a JavaScript function that ran off a click event to launch on page load and window resize. As you can see below, I commented out the section governing the click event and added the last line "window.onload," and manually added the class="resizerd" to the element it was working with.

The function isn't running at all. Chrome's Dev tools are showing "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'prevWidth' of undefined"  Did I mess up the syntax somewhere? Any advice for how to launch this on load?

Thank you!

```
//var clicked =  document.getElementById("buttonImportant")

  var resizeeContainer = document.getElementById('video_container');
  var resizee = resizeeContainer.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

  /*clicked.addEventListener('click',function(){
  if( resizeeContainer.className.lastIndexOf("resizerd")>=0 ){
  }
  else
  {
      resizeeContainer.className="resizerd";
  }*/
  myResizerObject.prevWidth = resizee.offsetWidth;
  myResizerObject.prevHeight = resizee.offsetHeight;
  myResizerObject.Init();
  //},false);


    myResizerObject.prevWidth = resizee.offsetWidth;
    myResizerObject.prevHeight = resizee.offsetHeight;
    myResizerObject.Init();

    var RESIZER = function(){ 

        this.prevWidth = resizee.offsetWidth;
        this.prevHeight = resizee.offsetHeight;

        this.resizee = resizeeContainer.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
        this.resizeeContainer = resizee.parentNode;
        this.resizeeStyle = this.resizee.style;

        var ratio = this.resizee.offsetHeight/this.resizee.offsetWidth;
        var that = this;

        this.Init = function(){
            if( that.resizeeContainer.className.lastIndexOf("resizerd")>=0 )
            {
                var resizeeContOffsetWidth = that.resizeeContainer.offsetWidth;
                var resizeeOffsetWidth = that.resizee.offsetWidth;
                var resizeeContOffsetHeight = that.resizeeContainer.offsetHeight;
                var resizeeOffsetHeight = that.resizee.offsetHeight;

                if(that.prevWidth!= resizeeContOffsetWidth)
                {
                    that.prevWidth = resizeeContOffsetWidth;
                    var desired = resizeeContainer.offsetHeight/resizeeContainer.offsetWidth;
                    if(desired>ratio){
                        that.resizeeStyle.width=resizeeContOffsetWidth*desired+resizeeContOffsetWidth*desired+"px";
                        that.resizeeStyle.left = -1*(resizeeOffsetWidth-resizeeContOffsetWidth)/2+'px';
                    }
                    else{ 
                     that.resizeeStyle.cssText="width:100%;height:auto;position:fixed;";
                    }
                }

                if(that.prevHeight!=resizeeContOffsetHeight)
                { 
                    that.prevHeight = resizeeContOffsetHeight;
                    var desired = resizeeContOffsetHeight/resizeeContOffsetWidth;  
                    if(desired>ratio){  console.log(ratio);
                        //that.resizeeStyle.top = '0px';
                        that.resizeeStyle.left = -1*(resizeeOffsetWidth-resizeeContOffsetWidth)/2+'px';
                        that.resizeeStyle.width = resizeeContOffsetHeight*desired+resizeeContOffsetHeight/desired+'px';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        that.resizeeStyle.top = -1*(resizeeOffsetHeight-resizeeContOffsetHeight)/2+'px';

                    }
                }

            }
        };
    };

    var myResizerObject = new RESIZER();
    window.onresize = myResizerObject.Init;
    window.onload = myResizerObject.Init;
```

Comment: @PST - I find your combination of italic and bold type condescending. I'd appreciate it if you could lend your advice without talking down to me.

That said- The function runs appropriately when the click function is un-commented, therefor proving that it works. My understanding has been that the click function served to specify what elements to work with and that by manually adding the class "resizerd" to that element I could avoid the click and then run the function onLoad

Comment: Hi technopeasant. Have you tried to look in the console in Firebug, or Chrome/Safari developer tools? If they write something out in the console, it will help us, help you quite alot :)
Another quick note, is that I recommend that you use jQuery - if possible, as a lot of the stuff you do, they make very easy :)

Comment: @Jesper Blad Jenson aka. Deldy - just updated the post with that info. Showing an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'prevWidth' of undefined"

Comment: Duplicate of/overlaps with [rewrite native javascript in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482420/rewrite-native-javascript-in-jquery).

Comment: @Dori - same code different question. At the end of the thread I decided to pursue this function in native script. and this is the first step.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to execute the function through the `<body>` tag?

Like:

```
<body onload="myfunction();">
```

Comment: no luck, it causes a few errors and doesn't work as I'd like it to.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the entire resize javascript function in the OnLoad="myfunction();" event of the Body of the page. I have done this to resize the page everytime it loads and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have this line:

```
 myResizerObject.prevWidth = resizee.offsetWidth;
```

That is probably giving the error. You've done nothing to declare `myResizerObject` so it cannot have a property `prevWidth`.

Somewhere down there you do

```
var myResizerObject = new RESIZER();
```

I suspect you want those lines in a more reasonable order :)

Comment: good catch. Don't know what I was thinking.. anyway, moved that line up to the top and now I'm getting a different error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: I suggest you take up @pst 's advice: remove all unneeded info, make a minimum failing test-case and post a question about that. It's hard to help if the problem changes after every valid answer because there are more problems than one.

Comment: I hear that. Definitely want to make it as easy as possible. The thing is that this code is as stripped as I can make it.. and believe me, I have. Would a jsFiddle help? Also, as it stands it is minimum failing.. just the one error.

Comment: Well, you could on your own strip stuff until the error disappears :). If you'd done that for the first error you'd have found it yourself as it is one of the first lines :). Now I don't even know what line the trouble is in....

Comment: maybe I didn't communicate it well. With the click function uncommented there are 0 errors and the the function in whole works as desired. I commented that out to begin working out how to launch it on load instead.. that's where the error i mentioned in my post showed up for the first time and when the function stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Such code should work just fine:

```
var myResizerObject = new RESIZER();

function UpdateResizerObject() {
    var resizeeContainer = document.getElementById('video_container');
    var resizee = resizeeContainer.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    myResizerObject.prevWidth = resizee.offsetWidth;
    myResizerObject.prevHeight = resizee.offsetHeight;
    myResizerObject.Init();
}

window.onload = function() {
    UpdateResizerObject();
};

window.onresize = function() {
    UpdateResizerObject();
};
```

Have it after you define the `RESIZER` class though.

Your mistake was calling the object instance variable before creating it.

Edit: some basic debug.. add alerts to the function like this:

```
this.Init = function(){
   alert("Init called.. container: " + that.resizeeContainer);
   if (that.resizeeContainer)
      alert("class: " + hat.resizeeContainer.className);
   if( that.resizeeContainer.className.lastIndexOf("resizerd")>=0 )
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

And see what you get.

Comment: @Shadow - thanks for the answer, I appreciate your time. Replacing the old code with your suggestion brings up a slew of erros. Theoretically it definitely makes sense to me though.

Comment: @techno maybe you need to keep `resizeeContainer` and `resizee` global, just take out their declaration outside the function.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - good call! gets rid of the errors, but doesn't launch the function on load as desired :(

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - gives me an error on the line with the elipses (...)

Comment: Those `...` mean that you should keep the original code in there, I just didn't want to copy the whole code but rather guide what changes to make.